# Tomcat running in docker container loads servlet twice

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, servlets

I have a problem with my web application when running it on Tomcat (with Docker).
Somehow the servlet is loaded twice. Initially it is loaded during startup and then it's loaded a second time when I make the first call.

I added a stacktrace manually in my init method to get the call stacks.

Stacktrace of the initial loading:

```
at [....].application.WebApplication.<init>(WebApplication.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1007)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:975)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1067)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1059)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Stacktrace of first call:

```
at [....].application.WebApplication.<init>(WebApplication.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1007)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:975)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1067)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1059)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't understand why Tomcat is trying to load it a second time.
When I deploy the app to my local Tomcat this does not happen.

web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
<display-name>WebApplication</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-
class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-
    value>[..].application.WebApplication</param-
value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5
RUN /bin/bash -c "rm -rf  /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*"
ADD target/my-webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
#For profiling use port JMI
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
```

Does anyone have an idea why tomcat is loading the servlet twice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added the stacktrace manually because I wanted to see where the calls came from

Comment: could you share how you run the container and WebApplication class

Comment: @andolsizied do you mean the web.xml?

Comment: no, the first line of the stacktrace `[....].application.WebApplication.<init>(WebApplication.java:87)` , is this your class?

Comment: @andolsizied yes, this is my class.

Comment: could you share it?

Comment: @andolsizied There is nothing in there which is causing the issue. The issue why this class get initialized twice. Also it's a lot of code ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163801/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-jobs).